# change page layout on link click vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm learning how to use vue.js
I've a shared hosting plan where I can only use html. I'm fetching the data I need using axios and a remote wordpress installation that will act as a backend only. What I need to know, is how I can change the DOM content of the `index.html` using vue if the user click on a link and I need to change the layout of the page because a different presentation for the contents is needed? 
See the example:

```
<div id="vue-app">
  <a href="#">link to layout 2</a>
  <div class="col-12">starting layout </div>
</div>

// after the user click the link (v-on:click) the layout change

<div id="vue-app">
  <a href="#">link to layout 1</a>
// layout change
  <div class="col-6">new layout </div>
  <div class="col-6">new layout </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read up on [Conditional Rendering in Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html).

You can have a boolean variable in the data compartment of your script tag and change it on click.

And in the tags put `v-if="your_bool_variable"`.

```
<div id="vue-app" v-if="layout_switch">
  <a href="#">link to layout 2</a>
  <div class="col-12">starting layout </div>
</div>

// after the user click the link (v-on:click) the layout change

<div id="vue-app" v-else>
  <a href="#">link to layout 1</a>
// layout change
  <div class="col-6">new layout </div>
  <div class="col-6">new layout </div>
</div>
```

Negate the boolean variable at the `@click` event.

Data could look like the following:

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "YourComponent",
        data: () => {
            return {
                layout_switch: true
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changeLayout() {
                this.layout_switch = !this.layout_switch;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't need to check if a value is true, I need to navigate the contents, so if the user click on a link, the whole page content needs to change. vue router can be the solution?

Comment: Yes in that case I would definitely use the vue-router. You can simply add the plugin if you launch the `vue ui` command and go into the web interface and it adds it to your project.

Comment: Ok. I'm not using the cli, I've included it from the cdn, now I need to understand how to use it.

Comment: Perfectly described here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/. I recommend starting off with a new project and then implement it in your actual project.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm having some trouble with it. I've posted a new question about  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61162050/vue-js-not-working-after-vue-router-is-implemented